# Prompting for input, "and was not expected at this time."

Tags: batch-file

I have a simple block of code. All variables have been defined before. What it does is ask for input of 1-4, and based on the response it will check if certain variables are at certain levels. If qualifications are met, it will return a scenario based on what happened. The following excerpt demonstrates this. It does not matter what choice you pick, it seems it always returns `and was unexpected at this time.`

```
set /p choice="By whom do you sit (1-4)? "

if !choice! GTR 4 echo Please enter a valid number. && goto thehogwartsexpress
if !choice! LSS 1 echo Please enter a valid number. && goto thehogwartsexpress
if "!choice!" EQU "1" (
    echo It was an interesting ride. You find out their names are Fred and George Weasley, second-years who enjoy gags and jokes. You tell them your name is !char_name!.
    if !char_ilvl! GTR 1 ( 
        echo You think they're slackers, but then again, they seem friendly.
        if !char_clvl! GTR 1 echo You talk to them occasionally throughout the ride. You've entered their frame of trust. You buy scrumptious delights from the witch's carriage. Character + 1. && set /a char_char=char_char+1
        if !char_clvl! EQU 0 echo You smirk at a few of their jokes and talk once or twice, but no more.
        echo [press enter]
        pause>nul
        goto hogwartsschoolarrival
    ) else (
        if !char_clvl! GTR 1 echo You all jester around and get to know each other. Looks like you've made two new friends for life. Character + 1. && set /a char_char=char_char+1
        if !char_clvl! EQU 0 echo You laugh a bit at their jokes and try to talk a bit. They think you're cool. Character + 1. && set /a char_char=char_char+1
        echo [press enter]
        pause>nul
        goto hogwartsschoolarrival
    )
) else if "!choice!" EQU "2" (
    if "!char_gen!" EQU "male" (
        if !char_rlvl! GTR 1 echo You introduce yourself as !char_name!, unveiling that their names are Angelina Johnson (black female) and Katie Bell (brunette). You easily become friends with the two. Charisma + 1. && set /a char_risma=char_risma+1
        if !char_rlvl! LSS 2 echo You sort of talked to them. Nice attempt. They like you, but they don't like you enough. Keep trying.
        echo [press enter]
        pause>nul
        goto hogwartsschoolarrival
    ) else (
        if !char_clvl! GTR 1 echo You introduce yourself as !char_name!, unveiling that their names are Angelina Johnson (black female) and Katie Bell (brunette). You talk to them intently throughout the ride. They talk about Hogwarts and show you a bit of the ropes. Character + 1. && set /a char_char=char_char+1
        if !char_clvl! LSS 2 echo You smiled at each other once or twice, but no more.
        echo [press enter]
        pause>nul
        goto hogwartsschoolarrival
    )
) else if "!choice!" EQU "3" (
    if !char_ilvl! LSS 2 (
        if !char_rlvl! GTR 2 echo You tried to talk to him, but to no avail. He simply glared at you, made a soft gag reflex and stared back out the window solemnly.
        if !char_rlvl! LSS 3 echo You talked not once.
        echo [press enter]
        pause>nul
        goto hogwartsschoolarrival
    ) else (
        echo You sit opposite to him, not saying a word. You plan to keep to yourself, pulling out your edition of "Magical Drafts and Potions," reading page 327. After seven minutes, you notice out of peripheral vision that he looked at you intently. You ignored him. "And what would your name be?" he said in a low, monotonous voice. "!char_name!," you say in the monotonous voice of your own. "Well, you appear to be of some hope for the new students. My name is Severus Snape, your potions teacher," he began with a sharpness in his voice. "I expect to see you in class. Don't disappoint me." With that, you both returned to your own heads. Congratulations, you managed to make friends with one of the most feared teachers in the school. Do well in his class. 
        echo [press enter]
        pause>nul
        goto hogwartsschoolarrival
    )
) else if "!choice!" EQU "4" ( 
    echo You wonder what Hogwarts will be like. 
    echo [press enter]
    pause>nul
    goto hogwartsschoolarrival
)
```

Comment: Sorry, but "I have a simple block of code" does not match the incomplete, large block of code that cannot demonstrate the problem you're having because of the missing pieces, including what was identified as "was not expected at this time" in the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'm not going to be able to go through this problem thoroughly unless I had around 30 min to look through your entire code, but what i can do is recommend you try using the `choice` command over the `set /p` since you only require a single digit answer which correspond with what you.

#### Replace:

```
set /p choice="By whom do you sit (1-4)? "
```

#### With:

```
choice /c 1234 /m "By whom do you sit ?"
set choice=%errorlevel%
```

And you wont even have to change the rest of the code!
Ofcourse this is assuming the error is with the input, as specified by the question, and that you have choice.exe installed on your computor.

Lastly I would recommend you set choice as a number variable through `set /a` as it seems it will stay a number the entire program and its in good practice to treat it like one, but ofcourse I don't know the entire script, so I'll leave that to you.

Yours, Mona

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is not with `set` but with `echo` in combination with `if`.
In this line:

```
if "!char_gen!" EQU "male" (
    if !char_rlvl! GTR 1 echo You introduce yourself as !char_name!, unveiling that their names are Angelina Johnson (black female) and Katie Bell (brunette)....
```

the closing `)` between "female" and "and" breaks the `if`(

You must escape it with a ^ :   ... `female ^) and` ...